# Is this idiomatic python for checking for None(s)?

Tags: python

My intention is to have a default value for `d` even if the item (identified by `key`) is missing in `adict`.

```
d = QueryDict('')
try:
    if adict['key'] is not None:
        d = adict['key'].copy()
except KeyError:
    pass

# use d ...
```

I cringe at the use of that exception handler. Did I violate any python code styles ?

Comment: Did you want "if 'key' in adict"?

Comment: The except clause is supposed to catch the situation when `key` is missing in `adict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be better:

```
d = (adict.get('key') or QueryDict('')).copy()
```

It might not be obvious what that does, though, so this might be preferable:

```
if 'key' in adict and adict['key'] is not None:
    d = adict['key'].copy()
else:
    d = QueryDict('')
```

Comment: `.get()` takes a second parameter for the value to return when the key is not found, so just use `adict.get('key', QueryDict(''))`.

Comment: @Karl: `{'key': None}.get('key', 'hello')` is `None`, not `'hello'`.

Comment: This way (with the `and`, rather than the `or` in my answer) is probably better -- since the general goal is to put the *expected* case in the `if` branch and alternate cases in the `elif`/`if` branches.

Comment: @icktoofay, thanks sorry about that -- didn't want to jip you

Comment: @icktoofay That's because you used get('key') which was None...{'a_different_key': None}.get('key', 'hello') Out[1]: 'hello'

Comment: @Derek: I know. My interpretation of the question was that the result should be `QueryDict('')` if `'key'` did not exist in `adict` **or `adict['key']` was `None`**.

Comment: @icktoofay Ah, your statement makes more sense now :) You were referring to the required output not what is actually given by running that statement.

Comment: Honestly, 99% of the time I see this kind of situation, it would be better to just put a `QueryDict('')` in the dictionary instead of `None` in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use:

```
d = adict.get('key', QueryDict('')).copy()
```

This assigns to `d` the value of `adict[key]` if the key exists in the dictionary, or if it does not, then `d` gets `QueryDict('')` as its value.

Alternately, you can use

```
d = adict.setdefault('key', QueryDict('')).copy()
```

This also assigns to `d` the value of `adict[key]` if the key exists, but if the key does not exist, then `adict[key]` is assigned the value `QueryDict('')` and this value is assigned to `d`.

Check out the documentation for dictionaries at [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
if key not in adict or adict[key] is None:
    d = QueryDict('')
else:
    d = adict[key].copy()
```

[Available as of Python 2.2](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: you could look at it as having 3 branches (1) if the key is not in the dict, (2) if the key is in the dict but set to None, (3) the key is in the dict.  For the first two, it sets d to a new dict.  For (3) it copies the dictionary value at the key.

Comment: Note: This is logically equivalent to what you wrote after my answer.

Comment: Sorry; I must have posted the comment after you edited your answer but before I refreshed the page to see it. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is much tidier than wrapping the code in a try catch.

```
d = QueryDict('')
if 'key' in adict and adict['key'] is not None:
    d = adict['key'].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find QueryDict in http://docs.python.org/

from http://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.

If you don't want to have an exception but would rather a default value used instead, you can use the get() method:

```
default = 'Scruffy'
a = adict.get('dogname', default)
```

Even more handy is somewhat controversially-named setdefault(key, val) which sets the value of the key only if it is not already in the dict, and returns that value in any case:

```
default = 'Scruffy'
dog_owned_by = {'Peter': 'Furry', 'Sally': 'Fluffy'}

dogs = []
for owner in ('Peter', 'Sally', 'Tim'): 
    dogs.append(dog_owned_by.setdefault(owner, default))

# dogs == ['Furry', 'Fluffy', 'Scruffy']
```

Comment: Sorry QueryDict is from django but behaves more or less like a dict